# Deploy only modified metadata in GitLab to Org

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, mdapi, cicd, mdapideploy

I followed this Trailhead "[Build an Automated CI/CD Pipeline with GitLab](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/automate-cicd-with-gitlab)" and have successfully built a pipeline that can deploy [or install] a package into an Org each time I push some changes into GitLab repo.

Now, I would like to build the same pipeline for the Org of my company. However, the org of my company has been heavily customized and I do not think it is wise or possible to begin with "Package Development Model".

Here is my question: in the .gitlab-ci.yml file, how can I detect changes in a new commit and deploy only these changed components to an org? (Very much the same as change set components, but to do it in GitLab pipeline)

I know I might have to use "sfdx force:mdapi:deploy". But how can I get the only the modified components to be deployed?

Thanks a million.

Comment: Does your org have over 50MB/10,000 components' worth of customization? What factors are requiring delta deployments?

Comment: Hi David, the factor is that I realized the "Last modified date" of all metadata in the package would be updated each time I install the package, including those all the unchanged component. That means if I include all metadata of my Org in one package, the "Last modified date" will be of no use anymore because it is altered during every installation. Is it possible to avoid this? Thanks.

Comment: If you're practicing CICD the source of truth for the history of your customizations really should be the version control repository rather than Last Modified Date. That said, no, you can't change the behavior of updating a LMD when you deploy a component.

Answer (score 2):

The Unlocked Package design automatically performs delta updates. If you're using Unlocked Packages to manage your metadata, you don't have to worry about manually calculating deltas, deploying "only changed items," etc. If you're dead set against Unlocked Packages, there are third-party tools, such as GearSet or AutoRabit, that can manually calculate deltas and deploy only changes. *(Note: I am not condoning these specific services, they are just the ones I'm familiar with. Please do your own research before making a purchase decision.)*

Comment: Hi sfdcfox, thanks for the feedback. It's good to know that there is automatic deltas calculation. However, I realized that each time I install the same package with a new version, the "Last modified date" field of all metadata in the package will be updated. This is something I would like to avoid. Is there any way to do it? Thanks.

Comment: @ZhuangPaulus No, it won't, unless a change was made. I have unlocked packages in my sandbox with wildly different last modified date values in the same package. It truly is a delta.

Comment: Okay thanks. I will give it another try. Another question here, is it wise (practical) to put all metadata into only one package for an Org and to do its version control in GitLab master branch?

Comment: @ZhuangPaulus Not recommended. There's a 10k file limit per package. We're a kind of large example, but we have over 35k files that describe our org's metata. It's pretty easy to hit that limit. You should have a branching strategy that includes at least master, staging, testing, plus any feature branches you need. See [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/212699/2984) of mine for my thoughts on the matter.

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox, in that case how do you decide in which package you put common metadata like "Account" and "Contact"? All teams working in our org use them and may want to modify them every now and then. –

Comment: Also I have tried the below command several times and each time all metadata got updated in the "Last modified field": 
" - sfdx force:package:install --package $PACKAGE_VERSION_ID --wait 10 --publishwait 10 --noprompt"
This is pretty weird to me.

Comment: @ZhuangPaulus The nice part about Unlocked Packages is that you can have individual parts in different packages (e.g. individual fields can be in different packages). We have a lot of "core" metadata that ended up in a central package upon which all others depend, but individual pieces, such as triggers, page layouts, etc are in a separate package. I'm not going to say that it's exactly a science for our team, as I'm literally building it now, but I would say it just takes an intuitive feel that you'll gain with experience. (1/2)

Comment: @ZhuangPaulus (2/2) You can also move metadata between packages if you make a mistake, so there's really no harm in experimenting. As far as the "Last Modified Date" bit goes, I'm not sure why it did that. I did check in my org, and found a field last modified in 2017, but is part of the package that I created late last year, so I know that it shouldn't necessarily update the audit fields. I'm just not sure what the conditions for the audit field being updated actually are.